# ¿Como compilar para macOS Sierra en Electron?

Tags: nodejs, electron

Estoy en Windows y compilé para OSX, pero al ejecutar el `.app`, me marca que está compilado el programa para versiones anteriores. La línea que usé y que está en `package.json` es:

```
"build": "electron-packager . MyApp --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=1.4.2"
```

Ya busqué mas opciones pero sin éxito. Agradecería su ayuda.